# How detect timezone change in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timezone, dst

I've got a Windows console Python application that for various unpleasant reasons has to use Python 2.7.

There are a lot of timing-related actions going on, and recently we had a bug occur when the program was running when the daylight savings switch occurred.  Upon further testing and investigating, I'm seeing that the timezone information is cached, and the application has to call `reload_localzone()` when appropriate to get the new timezone information.

How does my Python app know that timezone info has changed?  There's a Windows WM_TIMECHANGED event, but since it's a console app I don't know if I have any way to receive that message.

Comment: That really depends on what you're doing with your time and how. If done appropriately, you probably don't need to specifically detect that change…?

Comment: FYI - `reload_localzone` is a method from the [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) library.  The [implementation is here](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal/blob/3b574173b08cbd52d228e0511e6836f424393d82/tzlocal/win32.py#L130-L137).  It clears tzlocal's own caches.  Call it if you suspect the zone may have had reason to change. You may want to investigate separately how to receive a Win32 message (such as `WM_TIMECHANGED`) from your python app, then call `reload_timezone` when you receive it.